# Do any shadowspawn remain after A Memory of Light?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

The last battle is won, Shai'Tan no longer directly influences the world- are there any Trollocs, Myrdrall, ect that avoided extermination?

Comment: Your point is right and the answer incorrect. Because of undoing of the Bore, there was no Shadowspawn  - they were unnatural and only Dark One's support allowed them to live. Just like Blight stopped to exist, every Shadowspawn died, or stopped being one if it could live without Dark Ones help.

Answer (score 5):

While killing the Dark One would have severed the connection to all the darkspawn and most likely killed them, Shai'Tan was only sealed away, meaning that the darkspawn survived. In fact even after the last battle was over, Perrin worried about a possible attack.

"Aiel called to Perrin, "Ho, blacksmith, join us!" But he did not enter their celebrations. He looked for the guards. Someone around here had to be levelheaded enough to worry about a rogue Myrddraal or Dragkhar taking the opportunity to try for a little revenge."(p.893, A Memory of Light)

So, while a massive amount of trollocs and other darkspawn would have been killed, there would have been some who escaped or never left the Blight, such as the never seen Worms, though the Blight would most likely recede without the Dark One's influence.

Also, while the books focused on the Blight around Shayol Ghul, north of the Westlands, the companion book mentions that the Blight also reached to the north of Seanchan and Shara, though the Seanchan Blight was wiped mostly clean of shadowspawn and the Sharan's often deny even the Trolloc Wars.
[image]

Therefore, it stands to reason that at least some trollocs and myrddraal, etc. survived the last battle and would eventually have to be hunted down. And of course there were still darkfriends sneaking around and even a few Forsaken that were still "Alive" at the end.

I hope this answer was helpful!